# FUSE Camel route (using JAXB) can not convert the XML to Java object if it has the interface, any idea to solve it

Tags: interface, jaxb, apache-camel, xstream, jbossfuse

Recently, I have a project, it will use the FUSE Camel route to accept the XML as POST payload, and convert to Java object.

from(ENDPOINT_SAMPLE)
   .convertBodyTo(TestClass.class)

It suppose to convert the XML to TestClass object, but the TestClass is from the third party, it implements some interface, which cause lots of problem. Such as

2014-09-12 14:15:54,304 | WARN  | qtp1407394366-68 | AbstractJAXBProvider             | ?                                   ? | 
170 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 2.7.0.redhat-610379 | com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts  of IllegalAnnotationExceptions 
com.BBB.TestIF is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at com.BBB.TestIF
                .......

I used to use the XStream to convert the XML from/to Java, it works with interface, but JAXB can not do it, since this is handled by Camel internally, I can not change it to XStream.
   Please share your experience or give me some advice, I understand that I can mimic my own TestClass, but it may not be the good solution (since it is very complicated).
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If xstream works for you, then why don't you use xstream in camel as well?

```
from("foo:bar").unmarshal().xstream().to("bar:foo");
```

http://camel.apache.org/xstream